# How to find out which colours are in a colour palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot a simple graph with `scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")`. I generally like the colour palette, but I would like to change one line of my plot. I think I need to use `scale_color_manual`. I can change the colours this way, but how to find out which colours are used in the "Dark2" theme? I would like to keep all but one.

Comment: Here: http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Dark2&n=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RColorBrewer` library

```
library(RColorBrewer)

# Put all the color values (in hex format) from Dark2 into a vector
myPal <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")

# Remove whichever color you don't want
myPal <- myPal[-7]
```